# Calculation of Symmetry generator of cylindrical KdV equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-algebras, fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

I have calculated the generators of the cylindrical $KdV$ equation $$u_t+(u/2t)+uu_x+u_{xxx}=0,$$ 
but I got three generators, $$X_1=\partial_x,\\ X_2=2t^{1/2}\partial_x+\left(1/2t^{1/2}\right)\partial_u, \\   X_3=x\partial_x+3t\partial_t-2u\partial_u~.$$

But books and papers show that it has a fourth generator $$X_4=2xt^{1/2}\partial_x+4t^{3/2}\partial_t+(x/t^{1/2}-4ut^{1/2})\partial_u.$$ 
Can anybody provide me with a calculation of this?

Comment: MathJax please! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sir in the paper by "N. S. Zakharov and V. P. Korobeinikov, J. Appl. Math. Mech. 44, 668(1980). The doi: 10.1016/0021-8928(80)90071-4 and this result appears in the book by N H Ibragimov(on Vol1) and numerous papers. But in my calculations I have found only 3 generators instead of 4.